# UNION a final ROW in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm quite new to MDX and im having some trouble getting the following t-sql query to MDX.

```
select distinct
  System
from Systen
  where System <> 'MIS'
UNION
  SELECT  'ALL'
```

So far i got something like this. But i have no idea how to add that final row 'ALL'.

```
SELECT 
  {} ON COLUMNS,
  {[Concesionario].[Sistema].[Sistema].ALLMEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    -
      {
        [Concesionario].[Sistema].&[]
       ,[Concesionario].[Sistema].&[MIS]
      } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [DW]
);
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Sistema attribute is aggregatable it should already have an "All" member. The problem is that you are selecting from the Sistema level [Concesionario].[Sistema].[Sistema].ALLMEMBERS because you are using the .

So you could change your query to the following:

```
SELECT   
  {} ON COLUMNS,
  {[Concesionario].[Sistema].ALLMEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM
 (
  SELECT
    {
        [Concesionario].[Sistema].&[]
       ,[Concesionario].[Sistema].&[MIS]
      } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [DW]
);
```

But it would be even easier to just put the members you want directly in the axis rather than using a sub-select.

```
SELECT   
 {} ON COLUMNS,  
 {[Concesionario].[Sistema].[All] ,[Concesionario].[Sistema].&[MIS]  } ON COLUMNS  
FROM [DW]);
```

Comment: Ha, didn't think about that for some reason. Thank you!